# Issue when switching from networkd to NetworkManager

Tags: ubuntu, networking, oracle, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

On an Ubuntu 22.04 instance on Google Cloud, I can switch from networkd to NetworkManager like this:

```
$ sudo apt install network-manager

$ sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# add:
network: 
  renderer: NetworkManager

$ sudo reboot

$ nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
ens4    ethernet  connected               netplan-ens4
```

But identical steps performed on an Oracle Cloud instance results in:

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
enp0s6  ethernet  connected (externally)  enp0s6
```

Why is the state `connected` on Google Cloud, but `connected (externally)` on Oracle Cloud?